# If clause is not working as expected

Tags: asp-classic

I have the following if clause:

```
if ucase(displayanzeige) = "Y" \
or isnull(displayanzeige)      \
and ucase(bstatus) = "2"       \
or ucase(bstatus) = "1"
```

The first part of the if clause is working:

```
if ucase(displayanzeige) = "Y" \
or isnull(displayanzeige)
```

But the second part is not working:

```
and ucase(bstatus) = "2"      \
or ucase(bstatus) = "1"
```

What is wrong with the if-clause? please help

Comment: The tagging is contradictory... Is this ASP (asp-classic) or ASP.NET? What language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use brackets to help identify your if conditions:

```
if (ucase(displayanzeige) = "Y" or isnull(displayanzeige))
    and (ucase(bstatus) = "2" or ucase(bstatus) = "1")
```

You currently have:

```
1 or 2 and 3 or 4
```

The system could interpret this as "*1 must be true or 2 and 3 or 4 must be true*"

Placing brackets like:

```
(1 or 2) and (3 or 4)
```

Will tell the system that "*1 or 2 must be true, and 3 or 4 must be true*"

Answer (score 2):

Using brackets is a solution to your problem:-

```
 if (ucase(displayanzeige) = "Y" or isnull(displayanzeige)) and (ucase(bstatus) = "2" or ucase(bstatus) = "1")
```

Presently the system could not interpret the conditions as you want it to be. Using `brackets` is a better option for you.